# How to read .html file to Xcode UI

Tags: ios

I'm doing the task of changing the rtf files to html files. However,how to read .html files to NSTextView or other Object.I test the following API works well in reading HTML file.

```
NSTextView *showHtml;

[showHtml readRTFDFromFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"]];
```

The object showHtml can shows Html files as the browse does.

But The API readRTFDFromFile descript like that only read rtf or rtfd files.

Are there any API or method to shows Html file in xib.

I also test the API:

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTML:(NSData *) data documentAttributes:(NSDictionary **) docAttributes],
setAttributedStringValue:(NSAttributedString *) aAttributeString
```

But It can't shows the attribution except the string .

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What about a UIWebView?

Comment: This question is tagged with iOS but you talk about `NSTextView`. `NSTextView` is for OSX, not iOS. Do you mean to tag this with OSX or do you mean `UITextView`?